# Two SharePoint lists with different names, but same contents error

Tags: list, custom-list, list-definition

I have written a SharePoint solution which should create two SharePoint lists with completely different list definitions. If I deploy the solution, I get a strange behaviour. There are two different list instances but with the same content e.g. the same columns.

I deploy lists and list definitions from both lists in the same feature. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. So you have 2 list definitions, with 1 list instance each. And when you deploy them, both list instances somehow use the same list definition, leaving one list definition unused? - is this what happens?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what happens. Sorry for my bad description.

Comment: Start with the simple checks => Check the list definitions. Make sure they have different IDs in the `Type` attribute. Then check the list instances and make sure the IDs in their `TemplateType` attribute matches the ID from the list definition `Type` attribute they should use.

Comment: Thank you, the Type attributes of the list definition were the same. Now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comment solving issue posted as answer*

Check the list definitions. Make sure they have different IDs in the `Type` attribute. Then check the list instances and make sure the IDs in their `TemplateType` attribute matches the ID from the list definition `Type` attribute they should use.